# Date format in jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unsure how to format the date within Jquery.  The date is currently output as

2014-10-11 12:00:00 - 2014-10-11 12:00:00

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){          
     $('.alert-details').append('<div>'+ value.title +' , '+ value.start_time +' - '+ value.end_time  +'</div>');
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: A string is a string, you can write it the way you want to. I don't get it.

Comment: I am trying to convert to '11 Oct 2014 12:00'

Answer (score 0):

You have to chose your proper method

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

There you have toString() toGMTString() toLocaleString()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) plugin for datetime.

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // October 21st 2014, 7:52:42 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Tuesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Oct 21st 14
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2014 escaped 2014
moment().format();                          // 2014-10-21T19:52:42+03:30
```

Answer (score 0):

As @dariogriffo says above, there are several ways to display a date using javascript.  I found the code pasted in the snippet below on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) site. You can also find example code for all of the functions that @dariogriffo mentions.  They all return date in different formats.

[this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) tutorial tells you all about how to display dates in javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the date as a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toDateString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've seen this example but unsure how useful this is since months begin at 0 for January.  I don't understand the logic.

Comment: gotta say, dude, I don't really get what you're looking for.  Yes, months are zero-based.  December is month "11."  What are you trying to do?  Could you include some more details  and example code?